# Is This the Fundamental Group of a Compact 3-manifold?

Tags: group-theory, manifolds

Let $G=C_{19}\rtimes C_9=\langle a,b\ |\ a^{19}=b^9=1, a^b=a^7\rangle$ be a nonabelian group of order $171$.  Is there a (compact) 3-manifold $M$ with $\pi_1(M)\cong G$?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Jacob: I believe it's conjugation, $x^y = y^{-1}xy$.

Comment: @Steve: This is an interesting question, but what is your motivation for asking it?

Comment: @Jesse: I am listing all possible finite groups that occur as $\pi_1$ of a compact 3-manifold.  It is groups of these type I am having the hardest time eliminating (without using any of the theory of Seifert-fibred spaces).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\pi_1(M) = G$, then the universal cover of $M$ is a compact (because $G$ is finite) simply connected $3$-manifold, hence (by Poincare) a $3$-sphere, on which $G$ acts.  The [spherical space form conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_space_form_conjecture) then implies that $G$ is a group of isometeries of $S^3$, i.e. that $G$ is a subgroup of $O(4)$.  (See also [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thurston_elliptization_conjecture).)  Since $G$ has odd order, in fact $G$ is a subgroup of $SO(4)$, or of $PSO(4)$.  I don't think that your group $G$ embeds into $PSO(4)$ (use the isomorphism $PSO(4) \cong
PSO(3)\times PSO(3)$ and the known list of finite subgroups of $PSO(3)$), and so I think the answer is *no*.

(I don't know enough about the area to know if this kind of question can be answered without appealing to the full machinery of Poincare/geometrization.)

Comment: I actually was able to figure it out, but I used more topology than I would like.  I am still looking for a cohomological/combinatorial reason why groups such as these can't happen.  Anyway, here is the topological argument:

Comment: Since $|G|>2$, $M$ is orientable by a theorem of Epstein.  Capping off 2-spheres in $\delta M$ allows us to also assume $M$ is closed.  A toral (JSJ) decomposition implies $M$ is Seifert-fibred, and the structure of such finite groups implies $G$ must be abelian. Using cohomology and some theorems of Zassenhaus, I can actually list all possible finite groups.  But ruling out groups like the one in this question I can't do without resorting to the Seifert-fibred stuff.

Comment: I would also add that you need to be careful when applying the Poincare conjecture: you need $M$ closed!